# Performing asynchronous write operations over a TCP socket with Boost Asio

Tags: asynchronous, tcp, boost-asio

I am writing a Client/Server application in C++ with the help of Boost Asio. I have a working server, and the server workflow is something I understand well.

My client application handles the connect gracefully as shown in Asio examples, after which, it exchanges a handshake with the server. After that however, the users should be able to send requests to the server when and how they want, which is where I have a problem understanding the paradigm.

The initial workflow goes like a little like this:

```
OnConnected() { SendHandshake() }
SendHandshake() { async.write_some(handshake...), async_read_some(&OnRead) }
OnRead() { ReadServerHandshake() *** }
```

And users would send messages by using Write(msg):

```
Write (msg) { async_write_some(msg,&OnWrite), async_Read_some(&OnRead) }
OnWrite() {}
```

**EDIT:** Rephrasing the question to be clearer, here is the scenario:

After the initial handshaking is complete, the Client is only used to send requests to the server, on which it will get a reply. So, for instance, a user sends a write. Client waits for the read operation to complete, reads the reply and does something with it. The next user write will only come after, say, 5 minutes. Will the io_service stop working in the meanwhile because there are no outstanding asynchronous operations in between the last reply read and the next write?

Answer (score 0):

On an informative note, you can provide it with [io_service::work](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service__work.html) to stop an `io_service` from running out of work. This will ensure that the `io_service::run` never returns until the work object is destroyed.
To control the lifetime of the work object, you can use a `shared_ptr` pointer and reset it once the work is done, or you can use `boost::optional` as outlined [here](http://think-async.com/Asio/TipsAndTricks).

Of course you still need to handle the case where either the server closes the TCP connection, or the connection dies for whatever reason. To handle this case, one solution would be to have an outstanding `async_read` on the socket to the server. The read handler should be called with an `error_code` when/if something goes wrong with the connection. If you have the outstanding read on the connection, you do not need to use the work object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the IO service to complete a read, you must start a read. If you want to read data any time the client sends it, you must have an asynchronous read operation pending at all times. Otherwise, how would the library know what to do with the data?

Comment: I understand that I need to have an asynchronous read outstanding if I am expecting an answer from the server. I am doing that in the Write method.

But if I complete the write-read cycle, and it takes some time before the user wants to write again, will the io_service have terminated in the meanwhile because it had no work to do?

Comment: But it did have work to do, it was (and still will be) trying to complete the outstanding asynchronous read request. Making an asychronous request is one of the ways you tell the io_service to do something.

Comment: I mean after the read has finished. So i do async_read -> once it is done the OnRead handler is called, and in it I don't call any other asynchronous operation. Until the next write is initiated I dont have an outstanding read or write on the socket. Will the io_service stop working?

Comment: While you're in the OnRead handler, the read isn't finished yet. Part of an asynchronous operation is running the specified handler and until it finishes, the operation isn't finished. (And you'll typically have an asynch listen for new connections going on too.)